# Show $\tan(x)-x>0$ ,$\forall x \in (0,\pi/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know the derivative is greater than $0$ for all $x$ in $(0, \pi/2)$, but how to show $\tan(x)-x $  is greater than $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$?

Note: we have not yet learned l'hospitals rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \tan(x) - x$.

Then $f'(x) = \sec^2(x) - 1 = \frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{cos^2(x)} = \tan^2(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Hence $f(x) \geq f(0) = \tan(0) - 0 = 0 \quad \forall  x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: Thanks! I did not initially see that tan(0) is well defined.also, the derivative is strictly greater than 0 right?

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry for my laziness that I seldom consider what is inside a square and I say it is non-negative.

Comment: How does this prove the strict inequality that $x < tan(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\tan x-x$. Then $f'(x)=\sec^2x-1=\tan^2x > 0$ when $x\in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}).$

So $f(x)=\tan x-x\ge 0$, i.e., $\tan x > x$ when $x\in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}).$

Comment: How do you get from $tanx \ge x$ to $tanx > x$?